# With PayPal subscribe button, does the recurring billing continue indefinitely unless cancelled?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have created a `Subscribe` button using PayPal Standard button html code as below. The subscription billing cycle is monthly. For example, a user signs up for a Silver subscription at $150 per month or a Gold subscription at $200 per month.

**Question** : Will the monthly billing amount be automatically charged to the user every month `indefinitely` till user cancels the subscription, OR there is a maximum number of times it will be automatically charged?

I could not find any documentation on this, so just wanted to be sure.

**Subscribe button code**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XE3412D6UV2A">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/loadsprocure/paymentcompleted.aspx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="23V125,new,architect" />
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Plan Options">Plan Options</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="os0">
                    <option value="Basic">Basic : $100.00 USD - monthly</option>
                    <option value="Silver">Silver : $150.00 USD - monthly</option>
                    <option value="Gold">Gold : $200.00 USD - monthly</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(**NOTE**: All screen shots of  Notifications in this message are from sandbox environment of PayPal and not from live environment)

What I found was surprising. Even with a subscription button, you can end up creating a non-recurring payment if you use the code in my original post. But, if I added the code below, then it created a recurring profile **Without this extra code, the subscription billing stops after the current payment which you can see from a screen shot of subscription notification at end of this post.**

```
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"><!--creates a recurring payment-->
```

When I included above code and created a subscription, then I got the following notification which clearly states the next payment date and also mentions no stop date.

**Notification for subscription with recurring payment**

[image: Subscribe button creates recurring payment]

With the code that I have in my question post, the `Subscribe` button surprisingly creates a non-recurring billing. How I came to know about this was by looking at Notifications at https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/. Below is a screen shot of the notification for subscription created with original html code.

**Notification for subscription with NON-recurring payment**

[image: Subscribe button creates non-recurring payment]

The `src` variable is described in PayPal documemtation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/ is as below.

**`src` variable Documentation from PayPal**

[image: PayPal src variable]

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/

In short:

> When you support recurring payments for a buyer, you create a
>   recurring payments profile. The profile contains information about the
>   recurring payments, including details for an optional trial period and
>   a regular payment period. Both periods contain information about the
>   payment frequency and payment amounts, including shipping and tax, if
>   applicable.
>
> After creating a profile, **PayPal automatically queues payments based
>   on the billing start date, billing frequency, and billing amount.
>   Payments reoccur until the profile expires, there are too many failed
>   payments to continue, or you cancel the profile.**